# A space homotopy equivalent to its subspace implies the inclusion map is a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I find it not easy to understand the proof of corollary 0.21 of Hatcher's algebraic toplology. If the question of the title is true, I can understand it. But I don't know how to prove it. Can somebody helps me? Thank you!

Comment: Your edit asks a completely different question. Please ask that in another post.

Comment: OK. I will do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the inclusion of the circle of radius one with center at the point $(10,0)$ into the space $X=\mathbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: It is such an easy counterexample!